# Unable to pull Artifact Registry private images in newly created GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I cannot pull artifact registry images to a newly created GKE cluster with Terraform and a user-defined service account.

The terraform used to stand up the cluster is below.

```
locals {
  service         = "example"
  resource_prefix = format("%s-%s", local.service, var.env)
  location        = format("%s-b", var.gcp_region)
}

resource "google_service_account" "main" {
  account_id   = format("%s-sa", local.resource_prefix)
  display_name = format("%s-sa", local.resource_prefix)
  project      = var.gcp_project
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "main" {
  name                     = local.resource_prefix
  description              = format("Cluster primarily servicing the service %s", local.service)
  location                 = local.location
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "main" {
  name       = format("%s-node-pool", local.resource_prefix)
  location   = local.location
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.main.name
  node_count = var.gke_cluster_node_count

  node_config {
    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = var.gke_node_machine_type
    # Google recommends custom service accounts that have cloud-platform scope and permissions granted via IAM Roles.
    service_account = google_service_account.main.email
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
    ]
  }

  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = var.gke_cluster_autoscaling_min_node_count
    max_node_count = var.gke_cluster_autoscaling_max_node_count
  }
}
```

I run a helm deployment to deploy an application and get the following issue.

```
default       php-5996c7fbfd-d6xf5                                             0/1     ImagePullBackOff             0          37m
```

```
Normal   Pulling    36m (x4 over 37m)      kubelet            Pulling image "europe-docker.pkg.dev/example-999999/eu.gcr.io/example-php-fpm:latest"
  Warning  Failed     36m (x4 over 37m)      kubelet            Failed to pull image "europe-docker.pkg.dev/example-999999/eu.gcr.io/example-php-fpm:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "europe-docker.pkg.dev/example-999999/eu.gcr.io/example-php-fpm:latest": failed to resolve reference "europe-docker.pkg.dev/example-999999/eu.gcr.io/example-php-fpm:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
  Warning  Failed     36m (x4 over 37m)      kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     35m (x6 over 37m)      kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Seems to me that I've missed something to do with the service account. Although using cloud ssh I am able to generate an oauth token, but that also does not work using `crictl`

**UPDATE: issue resolved**

I have been able to resolve my problem with the following additional terraform code.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "artifact_role" {
  role = "roles/artifactregistry.reader"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.main.email}"
  project = var.gcp_project
}
```

Comment: The service account aren't automatically used for pulling images from registry. You have to create a secret and specify it in deployment. Refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: Might it be the roles on the SA are the issue?

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control

Might you need ```(roles/artifactregistry.reader)``` ?

Can you share the roles bound to the service account?

Comment: @Georgia I think this was it. See the Update I posted to the original post. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @ManideepKarthik By default the nodes service account is used which will either be `default` or whatever custom serviceaccount you specify.

Comment: @David awesome! Great to hear that's resolved for you! Permissions can be tricky initially but by adding them as needed you will be making sure you are giving the minimal required permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning comment to answer as it resolved @David's issue.

Because the user defined service account is being used for the node_pool the appropriate roles need to be bound to this service account.

In this case: `roles/artifactregistry.reader`

[Configuring artifact registry permissions](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#permissions)

Best practice is to grant the minimum required roles.

Comment: This OAuth scope is also required on your nodes as well as the role mentioned: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only

Answer (score 4):

As error says : **unexpected status: 403 Forbidden**

You might be having an issue with the Deployment **imagepull** **secret**.

For **GKE** you can use the service account **JSON**

Ref doc : https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key

Terraform create **secret** in **GKE** which you can use it to *deployment*

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "gcr" {
    type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
    metadata {
        name = "gcr-image-pull"
        namespace = "default"
    }
    data = {
        ".dockerconfigjson" = jsonencode({
            auths = {
                "gcr.io" = {
                    username = "_json_key"
                    password = base64decode(google_service_account_key.myaccount.private_key)
                    email = google_service_account.main.email
                    auth = base64encode("_json_key:${ base64decode(google_service_account_key.myaccount.private_key) }")
                }
            }
        })
    }}
```

Or use the **kubectl** to create the **secret**

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gcr \
    --docker-server=gcr.io \
    --docker-username=_json_key \
    --docker-password="$(cat google-service-account-key.json)" \
    --docker-email=<Email address>
```

Now if you have the POD or deployment you can create **YAML** config like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: uses-private-registry
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hello-app
    image: <image URI>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: secret-that-you-created
```

**Update:**

As per **Guillaume's** suggestion for **GKE/GCP** you can follow **[workload identity*](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)* option as best practice with other extern repo it might could not work.

Create the **IAM service account** in GCP:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create gke-workload-indentity \
    --project=<project-id>
```

Create a service account in the **K8s** cluster :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: gke-workload-indentity@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: gke-sa-workload
  namespace: default
```

Policy binding run below **Gcloud** command :

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gke-workload-indentity@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[default/K8s_SANAME]"
```

Now you can create the deployment POD with image in GCR/astifact repo just update the ServiceAccount

```
spec:
      serviceAccountName: gke-sa-workload
      containers:
      - name: container
        image: IMAGE
```

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: No, you MUST NOT use json key, it's a very bad practice!!!! Use workload identity instead.

Comment: Thanks, Guillaume for pointing it out. i have used `workload identity` to authenticate the Gcloud API never checked for `ImagePullSecret` to fetch images from external repo. it will work well for `GCR/Artifact` GCP definitely in the above scenario right.

Comment: updated the answer, thanks once again Guillaume for correcting.